# Is the 32 GB Nexus 7 compatible with Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I want to buy a 32 GB Nexus 7 to try installing Ubuntu - will it be compatible?

Answer (score 8):

I have just added support for 32GB variants via the ubuntu-nexus7-installer package (version 1.3):

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-nexus7/+archive/ubuntu-nexus7-installer/+packages

... working like a charm on my 32gb varient, let me know if you run into any oddities, No special rules apply for this image, just select 32GB and let the installer do its thing :)

Feedback appreciated!

Answer (score 7):

*Answering as someone who developed this image:*

EDIT: It was tested and released while I was flying home [and it works](http://t.co/Ufsz53wW)!

<strike>The answer is that we're not sure, but we think so. The hardware specs imply that it should be fine, but it's not been tested. If you had one and the hardware didn't change then you should be able to use a 8G image or the 16G image, but I'll reiterate that it was not tested and so there are no guarantees.  We have no current plans to build a 32G image.</strike>

Answer (score 0):

or you could install the new Ubuntu for Nexus 7.

[Nexus 7 Ubuntu 12.10 Installation Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation)

Comment: note that the wiki text here is wrong. the image we shipped is 12.10, not 13.04.